# How can I connect .env laravel in my web hosting ?, when DB_HOST: IP Public and Password ON,

Tags: php, mysql, ip, laravel-8, .env

I'm trying to set up my web aplication laravel 9 with connect MYSQL db host on my local server with DB_HOST:"Host Public/IP PUBLIC SERVRE LOCAL", always get eror when i'm setup at hosting. When i run my web code laravel in my laptop and connect DB_HOST:"Host Public/IP PUBLIC SERVRE LOCAL" it's success.
Always get eror  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to MySQLserver on '69.123.123(IP Public)' (110)

what steps did i miss when uploading to the hosting? What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from an external web server to your local database? If that is the case, you'll have to expose your mysql server to internet, and make sure the user allows connections from any host or your web server IP (if you know it)

Comment: my case was web hosting laravel to try to connect mysql db local server with there public ip host, i managed to try when i coded on my laptop, but when i posted on my hosting, got host ip error connection unkow.

Comment: Did you solve it? It's not the same to connect to you public IP from you laptop than from an external hosting provider. Even if you're using your public IP, the network routing will be internal and It'll work. Try to check if you've myslq port (3306) open in your firewall, and maybe you have to setup port forwarding on your router. Finally, I don't recommend doing that, can you just set up a database on your hosting provider?